# How to properly test an indoor map, when you're not on the site itself?

Tags: mock, maps

We have a indoor map app. The app is powered by both Google and Bluetooth GPS devices.

How can we mock locations when using this kind of technology? What are the strategies that can be used to test this?

Comment: Not enough to count as an answer, but... do you have the ability to send the app coordinates in the Google/Bluetooth GPS formats? If you can inject that information, you can send it known locations and verify that it maps them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use mock location indeed after you enabled them, have a lock here: https://www.xda-developers.com/fake-android-location/

Also won't be possible to download the map so that can be consulted offline?